# Select random record within groups sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, random

I can't seem to get my head around this. I have a single table in SQlite, from which I need to select a `random()` record for EACH group. So, considering a table such as:

```
id         link       chunk

2           a           me1

3           b           me1

4           c           me1

5           d           you2

6           e           you2

7           f           you2
```

I need sql that will return a random link value for each chunk. So one time I run it would give:

```
me1    |   a
you2   |   f
```

the next time maybe

```
me1    |   c
you2   |   d
```

I know similar questions have been answered but I'm not finding a derivation of one that applies here.

**UPDATE:**

Nuts, follow up question: so now I need to EXCLUDE rows where a new field "qcinfo" is set to 'Y'.

This, of course, hides rows whenever the random ID hits one where qcinfo = 'Y', which is wrong. I need to exclude the row from being considered in the chunk, but still generate a random record for the chunk if any records have qcinfo <> 'Y'.

```
select  t.chunk ,t.id, t.qcinfo, t.link from  table1
inner join
        (
        select chunk ,cast(min(id)+abs(random() % (max(id)-min(id)))as int) AS random_id
        from table1
        group by chunk
        ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
where qcinfo <> 'Y'
```

Comment: Is the number of groups fixed or variable?

Comment: Variable if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hackish, but it works... See sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81e75/7

```
select  t.chunk
        ,t.link
from    table1 t
inner join
        (
        select chunk
               ,FLOOR(min(id) + RAND() * (max(id)-min(id))) AS random_id
        from    table1
        group by chunk
        ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
```

Sorry, I thought that you said MySQL.
Here is the fiddle and the code for SQLite

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/81e75/12

```
select  t.chunk
        ,t.link
from    table1 t
inner join
        (
        select chunk
               ,cast(min(id)+abs(random() % (max(id)-min(id)))as int) AS random_id
        from    table1
        group by chunk
        ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
```

Comment: Curious: why use this instead of a much simpler `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY random()) GROUP BY chunk;`? Would it be more efficient for larger datasets?

Comment: He only want's a single row per 'chunk'. You're query does not address that requirement. (But I appreciate the `ORDER BY random()` idea)

Comment: @Declan_K The `GROUP BY chunk` ensures that there is only one row per chunk. (Allowing non-aggregated expressions in this context is an SQLite extension.)

Comment: That's pretty cool. No way that that would work in SQL Server.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I would never gotten that.

Comment: I ended up using MySQL so thanks for that code too! I just want to add a follow up here. Most of my groups are continuous (all records occur sequentially by and within the chunk) and contain 50 records. But some are not continuous and are scattered across the data set. But this method generates random IDs that do not fall within the ID values assigned to the group records if the records are not completely continuous. It has to do with the MIN and MAX thing. I guess even sorting wouldn't help this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that SQLite returns the **first value** corresponding to a group when we do a group by *without an aggregation*

```
select link, chunk from table group by chunk;
```

Running that you'll get this

```
me1 | a
you2| d
```

Now you can make the **first value** random by randomly sorting the table and then grouping. Here's the final solution.

```
select link, chunk from (select * from table order by random()) group by chunk;
```