# exclude records in sqlite subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, random, subquery

Based on this post, I've got this query that selects random records from a group (chunk). (see [Select random record within groups sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003074/select-random-record-within-groups-sqlite) for background)
But I realized I need to EXCLUDE rows where a new field "qcinfo" is set to 'Y'.

This, of course, hides rows whenever the random ID hits one where qcinfo = 'Y', which is wrong. I need to exclude the row from being considered in the chunk, but still generate a random record for the chunk if any records have qcinfo <> 'Y'.

```
select  t.chunk ,t.id, t.qcinfo, t.link from  table1
inner join
        (
        select chunk ,cast(min(id)+abs(random() % (max(id)-min(id)))as int) AS random_id
        from table1
        group by chunk
        ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
where qcinfo <> 'Y'
```

Given the following as data

```
id|link|chunk|qcinfo
2|Yes|me1|Y
3|rr|me1|
4|yy|me1|
5|uu|you2|
6|Yes|you2|Y
7|waw|you2|
8|wewe|you2|
9|eff|you2|
10|wefw|him3|
11|Yes|him3|Y
12|we|him3|
13|wefr|him3|
```

The following (note the comment line) gives what I need but does not exclude the Y. When I include the WHERE in the subquery I don't get any records and I can't figure out why.

```
select  t.chunk ,t.id, t.qcinfo, t.link from    marlintag t
inner join
        (
        select chunk ,cast(min(id)+abs(random() % (max(id)-min(id)))as int) AS random_id
        from    marlintag
--  where qcinfo <> 'Y'
        group by chunk ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the WHERE clause to the sub-query.

```
select  t.chunk ,t.id, t.qcinfo, t.link from  table1
inner join
        (
        select chunk ,cast(min(id)+abs(random() % (max(id)-min(id)))as int) AS random_id
        from table1
        where qcinfo <> 'Y'
        group by chunk
        ) sq
on      t.chunk = sq.chunk
and     t.id = sq.random_id
```

Comment: `NULLS` are excluded whenever you do a compare so you need to trap for that. Try `WHERE (qcinfo <> 'Y' OR qcinfo IS NULL)`

Comment: Aha! But now I'm getting records where qcinfo = 'Y'. Weird. Thoughts? http://bit.ly/14cMWaf

Comment: I also tried just selecting NULLs and I still get records with Y. Is this some aspect of SQLite's simple nature?

Comment: I also switched over to MySQL and I'm getting the same issues with this SQL.